# Ошибка socket.io Uncaught TypeError: io is not a function?

Tags: laravel, docker, docker-compose, socket.io, laravel-echo

Вот код

Все установлено

```
import Echo from "laravel-echo"

 window.io = require('socket.io-client');
 
 window.Echo = new Echo({
     broadcaster: 'socket.io',
     host: window.location.hostname + ':6001'
 });
```

Не работает, подскажите в чем проблема?

```
Uncaught TypeError: io is not a function
at SocketIoConnector.connect (app.js:7285)
at new Connector (app.js:6278)
at SocketIoConnector. (app.js:6247)
at new SocketIoConnector (app.js:7266)
at Echo.connect (app.js:7550)
at new Echo (app.js:7524)
at Module../resources/js/bootstrap.js (app.js:26893)
at __webpack_require__ (app.js:20)
at Object../resources/js/app.js (app.js:26856)
at __webpack_require__ (app.js:20)
```

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Answer (score 0):

Мне помогло изменение:

```
window.io = require('socket.io-client');
```

на

```
import IO from 'socket.io-client';
```

```
import Echo from "laravel-echo"
import IO from 'socket.io-client';

window.Echo = new Echo({
    broadcaster: 'socket.io',
    host: window.location.hostname + ':6001',
    transports: ['websocket', 'polling', 'flashsocket']
});
```